# Is there a relationship between driving distance and straight line distance?

Tags: distance, gis-principle

For fun, I created an FME workflow that emails me the 10 cheapest fuel princes within 10km of my house.

I calculate both the driving distance along roads and the straight line distance.

Knowing that with rivers, there is a relationship between the length along a river and the straight line distance. The ratio is approximately pi. This is called **[sinuosity](https://polygyan.medium.com/how-the-value-of-pi-determines-the-bend-of-rivers-38e22c2d048f)**.

I noticed today that the ratio of driving distance and straight line distance is approximately sqrt(2).  I assume this is because of the general orthogonal nature of roads. But I wonder is this phenomenon documented somewhere? Or is this just a coincidence with my 10 data points?

Comment: In forestry there is a "wigglefactor" (probably not the correct translation of the swedish "slingerfaktor") of ~1.3 when driving inside the forests.

Comment: My guess would be that it is a coincidence. If there happens to be a straight road from your house to the gas station, the ratio is 1. If there's a river (with no bridge nearby) between your house and the gas station the ratio would be higher.

Comment: A quick test from  my house to the three nearest gas stations reveals a ratio of 1.2, 1.15 and 1.17 .

Comment: I thought about it some more. When considering *only* orthogonal roads (N→S and E→W), the ratio will be `sqrt(2)` if the straight distance has a 45 degree angle (eg SW→NE). If you go say, 10 blocks north, and 1 block east, the straight distance will be `sqrt(10×10 + 1×1) = 10.04` (ratio 1.1). It can easily be deducted that the ratio will always be between 1 and sqrt(2) with this perfect street layout.

Comment: I just remembered that a long time ago, as a physical geographer, I learned that sinuosity is not a constant value, but rather is a function of several factors, e.g. slope, vegetation, .... A straight river has a sinuosity of 1, whereas a meandering river has (by definition) a sinuosity of between 1.5 and 4. So, even though a value of Pi defines a meandering river, that value may be different for other rivers. See this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meander